# raspberry pi no rainbow screen

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, boot-issues, act, activity-led

I have an another problem. My RPi (3 model B+) not booting. No ACT led, no rainbow screen, only PWR led.

Here is what i checked:
- Power supply (Raspberry Pi Universal Power Supply 2.5A, 5.1V Micro USB B, 1.5m Cable)
- Kingston DataTraveler 100 G3 64GB
- Toshiba Class 4 microSDHC Card 32GB
- Latest Raspbian
- Read Sticky Boot Problems

Answer (score 2):

There's been a few reports of RPi 3Bs where there's no 3.3V power supply from the on-board voltage regulator. If you have a multimeter check between pin #1 and pin #6 on the GPIO header (carefully because if you short any pins you could kill a good RPi).

Do any parts of the board get very hot very quickly? That's another sign of a dead RPi.

If it gives nothing on pin #1 then return it for a warranty replacement.

Comment: I don't have multimeter.